# Flash plug-in for Pandora shortcut

Tags: flash, adobe, pandora

Went to the Pandora website to listen to music and it wanted to install a quick link. Thought it was a great idea so I did.  But now when I click on the button to launch it, it asks for the updated version of Adobe Flash. I'm wondering if it's because the quick link is using a different service than Mozilla. I checked the plug-ins on Firefox and it shows 11.2.202.424 which is the most up to date one. Am I wrong in thinking the quick link is linked to a different service and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe dropped releasing new flash beyond 11.2 for linux.

The easiest way to use new flash is to install Google Chrome. It has built-in Pepper Flash. The newest possible version.

Another solution is to install pipelight. It is a plugin, which lets to use a Windows version of Adobe flash. It can be installed by running:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
pipelight-plugin --enable flash
```

A good guide is [HERE](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html). It lets enable not only flash, but silverlight too. This plugin works with Firefox quite well

Comment: I ended up installing Pithos which is more or less a Pandora bridge.